# How can I discriminate rows with similar values in a single select?

Tags: sql, oracle

I got rows like these in a table:

```
PRODUCTID | NAME  | LOCATION  | PRICE 
   1          X        R         5
   1          X        C         4.5
   2          Y        R         5
   3          Z        C         4.5
```

As you can see, the table can contain the same product but in different locations. All of the products are in the 'R' location, but sometimes a product can be in both the R and C Location with different prices.

What I want is that if a product is in both locations R and C, only get the location C, but if it's only in the R location, then just get the R one.

How can I accomplish This?

I have tried using sub queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM ProductLocation t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM ProductLocation 
  WHERE 
     LOCATION not in ('R')
)
and t.PRODUCTID='1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way is:

```
select pl.*
from ProductLocation pl
where pl.location = 'C'
union all
select pl.*
from ProductLocation pl
where pl.location = 'R' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from ProductLocation pl2
                  where pl2.productId = pl.productId and
                        pl2.location = 'C'
                 );
```

For performance, you want indexes on `ProductLocation(location)` and `ProductLocation(productId, location)`.

Comment: IMHO OP wants the symmetrical case where only one location exists (in that case :: change the condition in the subquery to `... AND pl2.location <> pl.location)` ) And replace the clause in the main query (and subquery) to `where pl.location IN( 'R' , 'C')`

Comment: @wildplasser . . . The inequality condition is there implicitly.  The `WHERE` clause in the outer query says `pl.location = 'R'` and the `WHERE` clause in the subquery says `pl2.location = 'C'`.  Hence, they are different.  As to checking for the two locations, that might be possible, but I interpreted the question (and its query) as saying that these are the only two locations -- and there are not any duplicates.

Comment: This answer did the job!!

Answer (score 2):

I think this may work also:

```
select * from
(select p.*, row_number() over
 ( partition by productid, name 
   order by case when location = 'C' then 1 else 2 end) rnum
from productlocation p)
where rnum = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1db2/10)